# How many kg of salt must be added to a $6$ kg $40\%$ by weight salt solution to obtain a solution containing $60\%$ of salt by weight?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$6$ kg of a salt solution contains $40\%$ of salt by weight . How many kg of salt must be added to obtain a solution containing $60\%$ of salt by weight?

I find 40% of salt in 6kg of a salt solution -

$ 40% X 6 = 2.4 kg $

And to have 60% , i need 20% more which is

$ 20% X 6 kg = 1.2 kg $

Why is my workings wrong ? Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1):

First, the amount of salt in the solution originally is $0.40 \cdot 6=2.4$kg  Now you need to add an amount $x$ of salt so that the total salt is $0.60$ of the total mass.  What is the total mass after you have done this?  How much total salt is there?

Comment: 24kg should be 2.4kg right? ;)

Comment: @TommyRäjert:  Yes.  Fixed.  Thanks.